# Why can't Matlab calculate the complex Number for Paillier-Encryption?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a programm Code for a Paillier Encryption with Matlab.

and I wanted to make a code to calculate this numbers
[image]

but when I try to calculate the exact numbers through my Laptop, my Matlab shows the result Inf like the picture below.

[image]

How can I solve this problem? Will it be the Problem of the Programm or my Laptop?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My normal [VPI](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/489112-how-to-use-large-numbers) approach is:

```
>> mod(sym(899778)^160109*sym(12312)^899777,809598649729)
   ans =
   594091908920
```